# Prove existence of subdivisions

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, riemann-sum

Suppose that $f:[0:1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a bounded function with upper and lower integrals:
$$\int_{\underline{0}}^{1}f=0 \ \ \textrm{and } \int_{0}^{\overline{1}}f=1$$

(a)  Prove that for every $\epsilon>0 $ there exists a subdivision $\sigma$ of $[0,1]$ such that the difference between the upper and lower sums satisfies $1\le U(\sigma ,f)-L(\sigma ,f)<1+\epsilon$

(b) Does there have to be a subdivision such that $U(\sigma ,f)-L(\sigma ,f)=1?$ Either prove it or find a counterexample.

For part (a), I did as follows:

Let $\sigma$ be the subdivision $\sigma =[a_0 =0\le a_1 \le a_2 ... < a_n=1]$. Since $f$ is bounded, $M_i$ and $m_i$ exist and, thus, $U(\sigma,f)$ and $L(\sigma,f)$ exist.

$\int_{\underline{0}}^{1}f=sup\{ L(\sigma,f), \textrm{all subdivisions } \ \sigma \ \textrm{of} \ [0,1] \}=0$

$\int_{0}^{\overline{1}}f=inf\{ U(\sigma,f), \textrm{all subdivisions } \ \sigma \ \textrm{of} \ [0,1] \}=1$

$m(1-0)<L(\sigma,f)\le U(\sigma,f)<M(1-0)$.

$m<L(\sigma,f)\le U(\sigma,f)<M$

We know that,

$\int_{0}^{\overline{1}}f\le U(\sigma,f)$

Choosing $\epsilon>0$ such that $\int_{0}^{\overline{1}}f=infU(\sigma,f)+\epsilon >U(\sigma,f)$

Thus, $U(\sigma,f)<1+\epsilon$  since   $U(\sigma,f)>L(\sigma,f)$ and $U(\sigma,f)<1+\epsilon$. We can say $U(\sigma ,f)-L(\sigma ,f)<1+\epsilon.$ We also know that $\int_{\underline{0}}^{1}f\ge L(\sigma,f)$ and $\int_{0}^{\overline{1}}f\le U(\sigma,f).$

Therefore, $\int_{\underline{0}}^{1}f - \int_{0}^{\overline{1}}f \le U(\sigma ,f)-L(\sigma ,f)$ so $1-0=1\le U(\sigma ,f)-L(\sigma ,f)<1+ \epsilon$

Have I done part (a) correctly? Also, how should I approach part (b) as I am stuck on it?

Comment: I wonder why can we choose an $\epsilon$? I suppose that it should be arbitrary.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is arbitrary and this should apply for some partition

Comment: So how can one guarantee that an arbitrary $\epsilon$ would satisfy the condition $\bar\int_0^1f=\inf U(\sigma,f) +\epsilon\gt U(\sigma,f)$?

Comment: HINT for (b): Consider the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0,&\text{if }x\text{ is irrational}\\2,&\text{if }x=\frac12\\1,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: I understand how $\epsilon$ does not satisfy the aforementioned condition. Should I try finding a relevant inequality satisfied $\forall \epsilon >0$ or try a different approach?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Assuming this is a counterexample I have to work with, should I state that since there exists an irrational number between any 2 rational numbers so, in any subdivision of the domain of $f$, the difference of the upper and lower integrals can not be one?

Comment: @JohnDoe: The fact that every subinterval contains an irrational lets you calculate $L(\sigma,f)$ explicitly for every $\sigma$. The fact that every subinterval contains a rational lets you calculate $U(\sigma,f)$ as a function of the width of the subinterval containing $\frac12$.

Comment: @JohnDoe maybe just use proof by contradiction for (a). Say that it is false, so for all subdivisions, $U(\sigma,f)-L(\sigma,f)\gt1+\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$. Then the upper integral would be at least $1+\epsilon$, which is a contradiction